# Where to put queries in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Where should I put my queries that access the models in Django?

Do I make a new vanilla class or is there a conventional way of structuring this? Maybe in the model class?

Comment: There is no best place to make queries. You make queries where you need them, when you need them.

Comment: Put the queries to the place where you need them. In most cases that will be the appropriate function in `views.py`.

Comment: @Matthias What should I do if multiple views make the same query? How do I avoid copying and pasting? Thank you

Comment: @tianz: Put that query in a function, call the function and return the result to your view(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They usually go in `views.py`. You may want to check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) to see how to make queries.

Comment: I have read it, but all I can see is that they access models.py through the interactive shell but it doesn't mention anything on where to put the queries in the code.